# How to create network in Ubuntu 20.04 from ethernet Cable

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have Ubuntu server and I need to connect it to the internet. Its local Ip address is **192.168.0.124**. This Server gets the internet from another server using switch ethernet cable. The **main server** that gives the internet has its private Ip address and has local Ip address **192.168.0.254**. Main server gives the internet also to **other Gentoo** server which has **192.168.0.106** ip iddress. I saw Gentoo server /etc/conf.d/net file and there is written like below.

```
config_eth0="192.168.0.106/24"
routes_eth0="default via 192.168.0.254"
```

In second **Gentoo server** internet is **working fine** but in Ubuntu server internet is not working.
I don't know where to start. Can you please give me some instructions on how to configure it correctly. Which files to change? I connecter ethernet cable correctly, only thing that I should  show its internet Ip that comes from **192.168.0.254** server.

Comment: On the server that is not working, type netstat -nr and post the output

Comment: ```netstat -nr``` command is not working. Since it does not have internet I cannot install it

Comment: If you say specific file data, I can post

Comment: Are you getting an error message? It is a standard command on pretty much all Linux builds.  Try 'ip route'

Comment: ```default via 192.168.0.254 dev enp5s0 proto static```
```192.168.0.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.124```
this is the result of ```ip route```

Comment: Looks good. Try traceroute 8.8.8.8 and post the results.

Comment: @AbuZaid `netstat` has been obsolete for more than 10 years. It is not expected to be installed on a system unless some other piece of legacy software depended on it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved an issue. It was related with `netplan`. I changed configuration file `/etc/netplan/ .conf`

```
network: 
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
      enp5s0:
        dhcp4: true
        dhcp6: true
```

Then type `netplan apply` to apply changes. In some cases `enp5s0` can be different for example `eth0`. It is ethernet name.